# MT7902 driver for Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, network-interface

I recently purchased a laptop from Asus (Asus X1504VA)
and installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on it. 
But I'm having trouble with the Wi-Fi adapter.

Specs are follows:

- Laptop model: Asus X1504VA
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (jammy)
- Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic
- Network: MediaTek device 7902

After a thorough search, I found that this question has been asked a lot
and this network adapter still has no support for Ubuntu. 
Other solutions suggest using a USB dongle and/or installing Windows. 
But I'd still like to use a Linux-based OS on my laptop.

Has anyone come across this issue? 
What's the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this has no easy solution, the card is not supported by the kernel: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-7902-1a3b-5520.

Previous answers on SE:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467679/wifi-and-bluetooth-dont-function-on-asus-vivobook-15-in-ubuntu-23-04
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493183/ubuntu-23-10-mediatek-7902-wifi-not-detected

If you connect an USB dongle (one supported by Linux ofc) you will have wifi connectivity at the cost of one occupied USB slot. This will most likely be your only viable option for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on another asus laptop that uses the same wifi card, you can buy an intel wifi card from amazon for around 25 dollars, just make sure it is supported, in my case, I had another laptop running windows, so I switched the wifi cards between the 2 laptops, luckily the one in my older laptop was supported by the linux kernel, here are the windows drivers for the 7902 (the one unsupported by linux):
https://deviceinbox.com/id/ven-14C3-dev-7902.html

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the source of my information was a false positive. Changing my answer to reflect that the there is no driver for the MT7902 in the kernel yet.

<s>The driver for the `MEDIATEK Corp. Wi-Fi 6E MT7902` added in the Linux `6.6.12` kernel series, as per https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=96859b01b7, while the latest kernel available on 22.04.x is the Linux 6.5 kernel series  via `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` meta-package</s>

You have the option of installing the most recent kernels, built by Ubuntu, as documented in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds .

However, there may be issues if you have secure boot enabled, as the kernel packages from the mainline builds are usually unsigned (meaning that the secure-boot process will not recognize them as valid boot binaries). To make such a mainline kernel of series 6.6 or later, you will need to follow additional steps to sign the kernel on your laptop, as documented in https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated my kernel to 6.7.9-060709-generic but I still have the same issue. Shouldn't the driver be discovered automatically by the OS?

Comment: @Loay It should. Maybe try the liquorix PPA for the `6.6.12-liquorix` or the `6.7-liquorix` kernel:  https://launchpad.net/~damentz/+archive/ubuntu/liquorix ? The listed kernel in the probe website lists a liquorix kernel too (`6.6.12-liquorix`).

Comment: Note that in the linked https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=96859b01b7 the name of the driver module supposedly for MT7902 is indicated as `wl` - which is the well-known name of a proprietary driver for *Broadcom* wireless chips. So I think this is probably a mis-detection, and it won't actually work. Or perhaps the user has forced the `wl` driver to load for the Mediatek MT7902, in a misguided attempt to get it to work, and it is skewing the results of the hardware probe.

Comment: I can confirm that MT7902 does not yet have any linux drivers. I have an ASUS Vivobook 16X with MT7902 wifi 6 chip, and Linux 6.7.9, and the inbuilt wifi chip does not work. I am using TP Link T2UB Nano, which works great out of the box.

Comment: @telcoM I wonder *which* wl? there's no plain wl driver, there are model names. I'd be willing to try even that, though I doubt it helps

Comment: @telcoM I wonder how that false positive came to be. Drivers usually declare the device IDs of the devices that they work for. Unless the driver source is modified and rebuild, it should not be possible. Further wouldn't it make sense to try with the mediatek drivers instead of the Broadcom ones?

Comment: @usretc If the Broadcom proprietary WiFi driver *now* uses a more descriptive name rather than just `wl.ko` for its kernel module, it's a relatively recent development - and a welcome one. However, there exists various third-party backports of older versions of that driver on the net, in Github and elsewhere. Sometimes inexperienced users find them and attempt to install them, without realizing that the version might actually be a downgrade compared to what is already packaged by their distribution or completely inappropriate for them (think "Linux newbies with Kali").

Comment: @Samveen Some drivers have a facility for easily providing new vendor/device ID pairs for the driver to try and recognize - because some hardware vendors re-brand OEM WiFi chips with their own custom IDs. This facility allows skillful users to identify their re-branded hardware and make it immediately usable without waiting for a kernel development cycle or building a custom kernel. Unfortunately it also allows unethical or misguided persons to easily distort the information they submit to linux-hardware.org website.